# Replicate Visual Studio 2013 custom GUI in winapi

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2013

I'm writing a GUI program using C++ and Winapi, and I want my window to have a custom border.  Visual Studio 2013 on Windows Desktop does this, replacing the typical window border with its own scheme while still functioning the same as a normal window with a close, minimize, and restore button, as well as being movable.

A long-winded way of doing this would be to create a window with the `WS_POPUP` style and intercept mouse events using collision detection.  However, considering Microsoft itself has created programs with different GUI styles, it occurred to me that there might be a more standardized way of doing this.  To be clear I'm not interested in using 3rd party APIs like QT or GTK.  I want to do this solely with the libraries that Microsoft provides.  Considering these limitations, is there another method to accomplish this?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want but 2 pointers: WM_NC... and Desktop Window Manager. well ok docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf That seems to be what I'm looking for.  Just one more question though, if you don't mind: how do I get the area of the desktop that isn't covered by the taskbar?  I still don't know this after like a year working with winapi for some reason.

Comment: Oh. I can't recall. I'd guess GetSystemMetrics? Just google it. ;-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Found it - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fb4de52d-66d4-44da-907c-0357d6ba894c/swmaximize-is-same-as-fullscreen?forum=vcgeneral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [example of a custom drawn window](https://mzaleczny.wordpress.com/2011/04/01/custom-drawed-window-sourcecode/).

In order to get the effect of a "custom drawn window" you need to paint the non-client parts of the window using [WM_NCPAINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd145212(v=vs.85).aspx).

Here are some related questions:

- [How to achieve Steam-like window using winapi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313403/how-to-achieve-steam-like-window-using-winapi)
- [How to draw custom border in win32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092673/how-to-draw-custom-border-in-win32)
- [Non client painting on aero glass window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634743/non-client-painting-on-aero-glass-window)