# How to draw custom border in win32?

Tags: windows, winapi

how to draw custom border, Actually i'am trying to draw 1 pixels border but failed, how can we achieve this?
i had tried this.but failed.i tried like this it works fine  when window does't have child window .. in my case on top of my window there  are 3 child window on this case i'am getting flickering.

```
           case WM_NCACTIVATE :
            {
                if(TRUE == wParam)
          {
         stateofWindow = true;
        InvalidateRect(hwnd,NULL,true);
          }
         else if(FALSE == wParam )
         {
        stateofWindow = false;
        InvalidateRect(hwnd,NULL,true);
         }
    }
break;

case WM_NCCALCSIZE :
    {   
        if (true == wParam )
        {       
           return 0;
        }
    }
    break;
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        HDC hcd = NULL;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        hcd = BeginPaint(hwnd,&ps);

        HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(165,165,165));; 

        SelectObject(hcd, hPen);

        RECT rcClientRect = {0};

        GetClientRect(hwnd,&rcClientRect);
        //GetWindowRect(hwnd,&rcClientRect);

        if(FALSE == stateofWindow)
        {
            MoveToEx(hcd,rcClientRect.left,rcClientRect.top,NULL);

            LineTo(hcd,rcClientRect.right-1,rcClientRect.top );

            LineTo(hcd,rcClientRect.right-1,rcClientRect.bottom-1 );

            LineTo(hcd,rcClientRect.left,rcClientRect.bottom-1 );

            LineTo(hcd,rcClientRect.left,rcClientRect.top);
        }
        else
        {
            HPEN hPen1 = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(255,0,0));; 

            SelectObject(hcd, hPen1);

            MoveToEx(hcd,rcClientRect.left,rcClientRect.top,NULL);

            LineTo(hcd,rcClientRect.right-1,rcClientRect.top );

            LineTo(hcd,rcClientRect.right-1,rcClientRect.bottom-1 );

            LineTo(hcd,rcClientRect.left,rcClientRect.bottom-1 );

            LineTo(hcd,rcClientRect.left,rcClientRect.top);
        }
        EndPaint(hwnd,&ps);
    }
           break;
```

Comment: In general, doing your own non-client painting is a bad idea.  (Just because you *can* do something doesn't mean you *should*.)

Comment: thank u for u r answer. i had tried it but its not working .

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit complicated. It requires correctly handling `WM_NCCALCSIZE`, `WM_NCPAINT` and `WM_NCHITTEST` at least.

Also note that I haven't tried ever since Aero came by, and I know Aero changed a lot of things: Under Aero, instead of just resizing the actual border, you use a border-less window and then call `Dwm*` functions to add border-like appearance and behavior (there was [an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN about that).

Comment: Thanks , can u give some idea to handle this. i tried but not get exact result.

Comment: IIRC, WM_NCCALCSIZE had some kind of gotcha, I couldn't use it right from the first try. Unfortunately I don't have the details handy. For your first test maybe you can ignore WM_NCPAINT if you just fill a rectangle in WM_PAINT, the objective just being to make sure the client area has the right size at all times.